# NullPointerException when scaffolding a table with composite key in Grails

Tags: java, oracle, grails, grails-orm, grails3

I have a table (Oracle 12c DB) which does not include an explicit ID column in Grails (3.3.9) and I'd like to scaffold it dynamically. Thus, I tried to create a composite key consisting of all its columns (none of them nullable), as that's the only workaround that I've been able to find, so that the code looks like this:

```
class AliasFrequencyDict implements Serializable{
    String frequency
    String unit
    String description
    String lang

    static constraints = {
        frequency maxSize: 10, sqlType: 'VARCHAR2'
        unit maxSize: 1, sqlType: 'VARCHAR2'
        description maxSize: 30, sqlType: 'VARCHAR2'
        lang maxSize: 2, sqlType: 'VARCHAR2'
    }

    static mapping = {
        sort 'frequency'
        version false
        id composite: ['frequency', 'unit', 'description', 'lang']
    }
}
```

In the controller, I simply have `static scaffold = AliasFrequencyDict`. When I try to access the index, though, I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` with a message reading `Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.gsp.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: [Byte array resource [view:-,-,aliasFrequencyDict:index]:21] Error executing tag <f:table>: null`. The stacktrace looks like this:

```
    Line | Method
->>  473 | createGroovyPageException    in Byte array resource [view:-,-,aliasFrequencyDict:index]
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Caused by GrailsTagException: [Byte array resource [view:-,-,aliasFrequencyDict:index]:21] Error executing tag <f:table>: null
->>   21 | throwRootCause               in Byte array resource [view:-,-,aliasFrequencyDict:index]
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Caused by NullPointerException: null
->>   35 | <init>                       in org.grails.scaffolding.model.property.DomainPropertyImpl
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     26 | build                        in org.grails.scaffolding.model.property.DomainPropertyFactoryImpl
|    118 | getListOutputProperties . .  in org.grails.scaffolding.model.DomainModelServiceImpl
|    540 | resolvePersistentProperties  in grails.plugin.formfields.FormFieldsTagLib
|    415 | resolvePropertyNames . . . . in     ''
|    402 | resolveProperties            in     ''
|    230 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . . in grails.plugin.formfields.FormFieldsTagLib$_closure4
|    446 | invokeTagLibClosure          in org.grails.gsp.GroovyPage
|    364 | invokeTag . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     54 | doCall                       in Byte_array_resource__view_____aliasFrequencyDict_index_$_run_closure2
|    200 | executeClosure . . . . . . . in org.grails.taglib.TagBodyClosure
|    102 | captureClosureOutput         in     ''
|    213 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|     48 | captureTagContent            in org.grails.plugins.web.taglib.SitemeshTagLib
|    156 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . . in org.grails.plugins.web.taglib.SitemeshTagLib$_closure3
|    446 | invokeTagLibClosure          in org.grails.gsp.GroovyPage
|    364 | invokeTag . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     72 | run                          in Byte_array_resource__view_____aliasFrequencyDict_index_
|    162 | doWriteTo . . . . . . . . .  in org.grails.gsp.GroovyPageWritable
|     82 | writeTo                      in     ''
|     76 | renderTemplate . . . . . . . in org.grails.web.servlet.view.GroovyPageView
|     71 | renderWithinGrailsWebRequest in org.grails.web.servlet.view.AbstractGrailsView
|     55 | renderMergedOutputModel . .  in     ''
|    303 | render                       in org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView
|    150 | renderInnerView . . . . . .  in org.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsLayoutView
|    128 | obtainContent                in     ''
|     63 | renderTemplate . . . . . . . in     ''
|     71 | renderWithinGrailsWebRequest in org.grails.web.servlet.view.AbstractGrailsView
|     55 | renderMergedOutputModel . .  in     ''
|    303 | render                       in org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView
|   1286 | render . . . . . . . . . . . in org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
|   1041 | processDispatchResult        in     ''
|    984 | doDispatch . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    901 | doService                    in     ''
|    970 | processRequest . . . . . . . in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
|    861 | doGet                        in     ''
|    846 | service . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     55 | doFilterInternal             in org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter
|     77 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . in org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter
|     67 | doFilterInternal             in org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter
|   1149 | runWorker . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    624 | run                          in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    748 | run . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Why is that so? How can I fix this so that the scaffolding starts working again?

Comment: Seeing the same thing with Grails 3.3.11. Did you find a fix?

Comment: @nickdos regretfully I was doing it for a past gig which sadly I've long forgotten :( I don't even remember if I found a fix or just some hacky workaround, let alone what the exact fix could have been. Sorry!